# runtime error 6 overflow

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am getting a Runtime error 6 'overflow' message on the following code upon arriving at the line starting with 'minimo'.  It was working fine until recently. After providing some cosmetic-type updates to its underlying form this message has arrived and I can't understand why.

```
'Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open "select min(autonumerazione) from tblDashboard01", CurrentProject.Connection

Do While Not rs.EOF
minimo = rs.Fields(0)
rs.MoveNext
Loop
minimo = minimo - 1
st_Sql = "update tbldashboard01 set MasterLevel = autonumerazione - " & minimo & ""
Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_Sql)
```

Comment: How is *minimo* declared?  If it's Integer, it can't accept a value larger than 32,767.  What is the value of `rs.Fields(0)` when you hit that error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try inserting the following line at the start of the program:

```
Dim minimo as Long
```

Comment: @MarcheseIlChihuahua – My practice is to insert `Option Explicit` as the first line of every program module (file). This forces me to declare every variable using `Dim` statement and this way I can avoid many errors similar to this one.

Comment: Miroxlav, just as an FYI i had declared that variable as Integer prior to taking your advice. After a bit of research it seemed to me that this problem resulted from the fact that the underlying field which was being extracted was an automatic numerical field which was exceeding a large number. I am still a bit confused as to why this is a problem .

Comment: @MarcheseIlChihuahua - honestly, I'm not sure how automatic data types work in some scenarios. The best approach is as follows: (1) check data type of your database field (of field `autoenumerazione` in this case) (2) determine maximum and minimum value for this data type (use **MS Access Help**) (3) find corresponding data type in VBA (Integer? Long? use **VBA Help**) (4) declare variable of given data type. If you determined data type correctly, it will be large enough to accept all values coming from the database.

Comment: this is an old post but good god I was tearing my head out for a solution and this fixed it. thank you so much!